# Register custom Pomm converters from a bundle?

Tags: symfony, pomm

#### The need

Automatically add custom converters (coming from a bundle) to an existing session (the default of my application).

I don't find a way to achieve this, so I have tried another approach.

#### Context

- Symfony application with `pomm-bundle: ~2.4`.
- My application has a session flagged as default and use specific converters (add with a custom `SessionBuilder::postConfigure`).
- I have a bundle (I own it) in which I declare another session (not flagged as default) with registered converters specific to my bundle.
- The main need was to add custom converters from a bundle to the default session, but I don't find how to achieve this, so I have declared a second session in the bundle

#### Encountered bug

In my application, I don' know why, when I get models of the project, they are randomly attached to the default session or the session add by the bundle (I guess it's not random, but I don't figure out).
This result in `ConverterException` like `No converter registered for type 'public.validation_type'` when a model use the wrong session.

`The need` is the main goal, I do not need this second session, it was only to test an alternative solution because I don't find howto extends the default one through my bundle (I've tried with `CompilerPass`, but I don't really know where to plug.)

Answer (score 0):

A [good practice](https://github.com/pomm-project/Foundation/blob/master/documentation/foundation.rst#session-customization) is to declare your own `SessionBuilder` class in your project and [set the configuration](https://github.com/pomm-project/ModelManager/blob/master/documentation/model_manager.rst#configuration) to use it. Ideally, it is located at the root of your project's Pomm namespace.

This class must extend `SessionBuilder` and it can overload the `initializeConverterHolder()` method to add its own converters to the session.

Here is an example:

```php
<?php

namespace Your\App\Model;

use PommProject\Foundation\Converter\ConverterHolder;
use PommProject\Foundation\Converter\PgHstore;
use PommProject\ModelManager\SessionBuilder as Base;

class SessionBuilder extends Base
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function initializeConverterHolder(ConverterHolder $converter_holder)
    {
        parent::initializeConverterHolder($converter_holder);

        $converter_holder
            ->registerConverter('Hstore', new PgHstore(), ['public.hstore'])
        ;
    }
}
```